# What does "approach" mean?

Tags: criminal-law, florida

The "Florida Computer Crimes Act" defines "access" in Florida statutes Ch. 815.03(1) as follows:

> “Access” means to approach, instruct, communicate with, store data in,
> retrieve data from, or otherwise make use of any resources of a
> computer, a computer system, a computer network, or an electronic
> device.

What does it mean to "approach" a computer system?

Comment: I'm guessing it's physical proximity with intent to interact.

Comment: Statute writers often confuse detail and precision. They seem to hope that if they just spell out enough details, they will cover all possible cases. Instead, they end up baffling readers, who are must try to guess what the law makers could possibly have meant.